# Can I track down where a SIGINT came from if it's not from a user?

Tags: linux, signals, debugging

I have a long running (3 hours) shell script running on a CentOS 7 machine. The script runs a loop with an inner loop and calls `curl` in each iteration.

I'm starting the script with [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/) because it's already on the system and it's good for managing processes. However it seems that it might not be good for shell scripts. When I came in this morning I saw that PM2 had restarted my shell script 6 times. The PM2 logs say it received a SIGINT and was restarted. Since this script results in data being pushed to a database that means my data has been pushed 6 times. That's no bueno.

I'm the only person that logs into the box so it's not another user.

So, next question is whether this is a bug in PM2 or a legit SIGINT. Which begs the question: if it is legit, where is it coming from? I have to determine (if possible) if the OS is somehow killing this process before I submit this as a bug in PM2 (which seems like the most likely thing).

Comment: Did you track where this signal came from? I'm experiencing the same with pm2 and nodejs app.

Comment: No, this stopped happening when I put my node processes in docker. I think it was an issue between PM2 and CentOS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`sysdig`](http://www.sysdig.org) can monitor for these using the `evt.type=kill` filter:

```
# terminal uno
perl -E 'warn "$$\n"; $SIG{INT}= sub { die "aaaaargh" }; sleep 999'

# terminal dos
sysdig -p '%proc.pname[%proc.ppid]: %proc.name -> %evt.type(%evt.args)' evt.type=kill

# terminal tres
kill -INT 11943  # or whatever
```

A more specific filter may be necessary to avoid e.g. `systemd` spam from cluttering up the `sysdig` output, or `grep` for your process names or pids:

```
# sysdig -p '%proc.pname[%proc.ppid]: %proc.name -> %evt.type(%evt.args)' evt.type=kill
systemd[1]: systemd-udevd -> kill(pid=11969(systemd-udevd) sig=15(SIGTERM) )
systemd[1]: systemd-udevd -> kill(res=0 )
systemd[1]: systemd-udevd -> kill(pid=11970(systemd-udevd) sig=15(SIGTERM) )
systemd[1]: systemd-udevd -> kill(res=0 )
systemd[1]: systemd-udevd -> kill(pid=11971(systemd-udevd) sig=15(SIGTERM) )
systemd[1]: systemd-udevd -> kill(res=0 )
sshd[11945]: bash -> kill(pid=11943(perl) sig=2(SIGINT) )
sshd[11945]: bash -> kill(res=0 )
```